# Difference between ～ことは and ～ことが

Tags: meaning, particle-は, particle-が

What is the difference between:

> 練習すること**が**大切です。
> 練習すること**は**大切です。

Comment: Have you checked any learning resources, your grammar book, etc.? What have you found so far?

Comment: Personally, I feel that the first sentence (が) is simply stating a fact: `Practicing is important`, and the latter (は) is placing some emphasis on the 'practicing' part of the sentence, sort of saying how it's specifically practicing that is important, rather than something else.